# How to resolve hibernate caching exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jboss5.x, hibernate-cache

I can see caching exception sometimes only, I am not able to reproduce as well.
So just wanted to know how shall I proceed.

We are using Jboss As 5.1 and Hibernate 3.3.2.GA version

We have an entity

```
 @Table(name = "TBL_COUNTRY")
 @Entity
 @Cache(region="/country", usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
 public class Country implements Serializable {
}
```

Hibernate config:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

    <!-- Clustered cache with TreeCache -->
    <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
    name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
    name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.jbc2.JndiMultiplexedJBossCacheRegionFactory" />

    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.query.localonly" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cachefactory" value="java:CacheManager" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.entity" value="mvcc-entity" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.jbc2.cfg.query"  value="local-query" />
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="ecommerce"/>

    <property name="jboss.depends.1" value="jboss:service=Naming"/>
    <property name="jboss.depends.2" value="jboss:service=TransactionManager"/>
    <property name="jboss.depends.3" value="jboss.cache:service=CacheManager"/>
    <property name="jboss.depends.4" value="jboss.jca:name=ecomm-ds,service=ManagedConnectionPool"/>
</properties>
```

Log is attached

> 2017-07-26 18:31:45,849 WARN 
>   [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLoggerI18N]
>   (http-XXXXXXXXXX%2F10.137.96.103-8080-17)
>   [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator_2]
>   TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for
>   com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple@1e9b02ed
>   org.jboss.cache.optimistic.DataVersioningException: Transaction
>   attempted to create /ecommerce/currency/QUERY/sql: select
>   currency2_.ID as ID7_, currency2_.CONVERSION_FACTOR as CONVERSION2_7_,
>   currency2_.ISO_NAME as ISO3_7_, currency2_.NAME as NAME7_,
>   currency2_.SYMBOL as SYMBOL7_ from TBL_COUNTRY country0_ left outer
>   join TBL_SHIPPING_ZONE_COUNTRY country0_1_ on
>   country0_.ID=country0_1_.COUNTRY_ID inner join TBL_SHIPPING_ZONES
>   shippingzo1_ on country0_1_.SHIPPING_ZONE_ID=shippingzo1_.ID inner
>   join TBL_CURRENCIES currency2_ on
>   shippingzo1_.CURRENCY_ID=currency2_.ID where country0_.ID=?;
>   parameters: ; named parameters: {countryCode=US} anew.  It has already
>   been created since this transaction started, by another (possibly
>   remote) transaction.  We have a concurrent creation event.
>           at org.jboss.cache.interceptors.OptimisticValidatorInterceptor.visitOptimisticPrepareCommand(OptimisticValidatorInterceptor.java:116)
>           at org.jboss.cache.commands.tx.OptimisticPrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(OptimisticPrepareCommand.java:55)
>           at org.jboss.cache.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:116)
>           at org.jboss.cache.interceptors.OptimisticLockingInterceptor.visitOptimisticPrepareCommand(OptimisticLockingInterceptor.java:89)
>           at org.jboss.cache.commands.tx.OptimisticPrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(OptimisticPrepareCommand.java:55)
>           at org.jboss.cache.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:116)
>           at org.jboss.cache.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.handleDefault(CommandInterceptor.java:131)
>           at org.jboss.cache.commands.AbstractVisitor.visitOptimisticPrepareCommand(AbstractVisitor.java:155)
>           at org.jboss.cache.commands.tx.OptimisticPrepareCommand.acceptVisitor(OptimisticPrepareCommand.java:55)
>           at org.jboss.cache.interceptors.base.CommandInterceptor.invokeNextInterceptor(CommandInterceptor.java:116)
>           at org.jboss.cache.interceptors.TxInterceptor.runPreparePhase(TxInterceptor.java:682)
>           at org.jboss.cache.interceptors.TxInterceptor$LocalSynchronizationHandler.beforeCompletion(TxInterceptor.java:1102)
>           at org.jboss.cache.interceptors.OrderedSynchronizationHandler.beforeCompletion(OrderedSynchronizationHandler.java:81)
>           at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:101)
>           at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:269)
>           at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:89)
>           at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:177)
>           at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1423)
>           at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:137)
>           at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
>           at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.endTransaction(TxPolicy.java:170)
>           at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInOurTx(TxPolicy.java:87)
>           at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:190)
>           at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
>           at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RunAsSecurityInterceptorv2.invoke(RunAsSecurityInterceptorv2.java:94)
>           at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.java:201)
>           at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
>           at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
>           at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
>           at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
>           at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)
>           at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
>           at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.localInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:323)
>           at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.invokeEndpoint(StatelessContainer.java:691)
>           at org.jboss.wsf.container.jboss50.invocation.InvocationHandlerEJB3.invoke(InvocationHandlerEJB3.java:96)
>           at org.jboss.ws.core.server.ServiceEndpointInvoker.invoke(ServiceEndpointInvoker.java:222)
>           at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:474)
>   //omitted

Comment: Share please simple project with this problem part via git (to check configuration\mapping\TM...). This issue can have different reasons.

Comment: Do you write region any time? Its just ready only?

Comment: Yes We need to write very few times. mostly it is read only

Comment: You can not update it, since it read only. You have to change the strategy.

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs to read, but not modify, instances of a persistent class, a read-only cache can be used. This is the simplest and optimal performing strategy. It is even safe for use in a cluster. [More details.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache-readonly)

Comment: `Strategy: nonstrict read/write` for occasional update of data. Reason can be found in exception trace `Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted] Could not commit transaction.`